# Setting default value on a Kafka Connect Struct Schema

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I seem to be missing something obvious here, or Kafka Connect is incredibly broken, which seems unlikely.

I'm trying to set the default value on a Kafka Connect's schema of type struct. The first issue I ran into was a chicken and egg: to create a `Struct`, for the default value, I need to pass its schema, but I can only set the default value while making the schema itself. That can be overcome by either making a copy of the schema, without the default, or by calling `build()` on the builder to get a current copy of it.

I thought I might have problems later with the `optional` field, since it's set to `null` on the builder and anything else on the schema, and there's no way to force that flag to anything other than `true`.

But I fail before that, because the class of the schema builder is `SchemaBuilder` and the class of the default value is `ConnectSchema`, and there seems to be no way around *that*.

So, what am I missing? Or is this truly incredibly broken?

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing is that, as implied in the question, `SchemaBuilder` is a `Schema`, so instead of passing `builder.build()` to make the default value, `builder` being the `SchemaBuilder` in question, I just have to pass `builder`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been beating my head against this issue for a few days now, and eventually came across https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/devguide.html#manage-schemas which includes this code snippet:

```java
Schema schema = SchemaBuilder.struct().name(NAME)
    .field("name", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .field("age", Schema.INT_SCHEMA)
    .field("admin", new SchemaBuilder.boolean().defaultValue(false).build())
    .build();
```

I had been trying to add the `.defaultValue()` method *after* declaring the Field, rather than as part of it. Since my SMT has to handle a variety of schema field types, I wrote a small function to provide the appropriate `Schema` via an anonymous `SchemaBuilder`; after reviewing https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/ConnectSchema.java#L59 I found that

`SchemaBuilder.array(theSchema).defaultValue(new ArrayList<String>())`

works nicely for the array type.